# Ajax передать через POST ячейки таблицы

Tags: javascript, ajax

Подскажите, сейчас ajax передает значение ячейки и айди, где произошло редактирование, но если мы ставим в обновление это значение он обновляет все поля таблицы по этому значению, помогите подправить код, как я понимаю надо передать название столбца, чтобы он правильно передавать значение в нужную ячейку.

```js
$(".td").focusout(function () {
    var id = this.id;
    var split_id = id.split("_");
    var field_name = split_id[0];
    var value = $(this).text();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'up.php',//файл с php скриптом, обновляющий данные в бд
        type: 'post',
        data: { id: field_name, value: value },// отправляем имя поля, новое значение и id, чтобы определить, что конкретно и как надо обновить в таблице
        success: function (response) {
            console.log('Save successfully');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
$id = $_POST['id'];
$value = $_POST['value'];
//подключаемся к бд
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'web', 'admin','table');
//делаем запрос на обновление строки
$query = "UPDATE `test` SET `name`='".$value."', `surname`= '".$value."' WHERE `id`=$id";
mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

Comment: язык, на котором это все написано, называется **явасрипт**

Comment: Тупо и за интереса как это можно на js сделать?

Comment: Первые две буквы в AJAX означают Asynchronous JavaScript. Не Asynchronous РНР. Все эти ячейки находятся в браузере. И отправить их можно только яваскриптом. Потому что РНР в браузере нет.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос закрыт.

```js
$(".td").focusout(function () {
    var id = this.id;
    var split_id = id.split("_");
    var field_name = split_id[0];
    var edit_id = split_id[1];
    var value = $(this).text();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'up.php',//файл с php скриптом, обновляющий данные в бд
        type: 'post',
        data: { field: field_name, value: value, id: edit_id },// отправляем имя поля, новое значение и id, чтобы определить, что конкретно и как надо обновить в таблице
        success: function (response) {
            console.log('Save successfully');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<td contentEditable='true' class='td' id='name_". $row["id"]  ."'>" . $row["name"]  . "</td>
<?php 
$field= $_POST['field'];
$value = $_POST['value'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
//подключаемся к бд
$con = mysqli_connect('', 'web', 'adminbifk','table');
//делаем запрос на обновление строки
$query = "UPDATE test SET ".$field."='".$value."' WHERE id=".$id;
mysqli_query($con,$query);
?>
```

Comment: рекомендую почитать про SQL инъекции

Comment: Спасибо за код, пригодиться